# como traer las tablas de una BD especifica?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, tablas

Estoy haciendo unas consultas sql, y quiero seleccionar las tablas de una base de datos especificas. Mi base de datos es: **bd_inventario**

`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

solo tengo esta consulta, pero trae todas las tablas de todas las base de datos.

¿Cómo le hago para traer las tablas de la base de datos?

Comment: Hola josue, podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te fue uril, gracias

Comment: @Japv si me fue util

Comment: Que bueno que te fue útil, podrías marcar por favor la respuesta como aceptada y si lo deseas darle un voto también, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MiEsquema';
```

Debes especificar el esquema al que pertenecen las tablas que quieres mostrar, para eso en la **claúsula where** pones:

```
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MiEsquema'
```

siendo **'MiEsquema'**, el esquema que deseas.